# Subinterval counting distribution of a Poisson counting process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Suppose $N(\omega,t)$ is a [homogeneous Poisson counting process][1] with a constant parameter $\lambda,\,\forall\omega \in\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space. Given positive real numbers $T$ and $\tau$, and non-negative integer $n$, what is the probability that $N(\omega,t)$ counts exactly $n$ points within at least one subinterval $[t,t+\tau]$ of $[0,T]$, or Prob$\big(\bigcup_t\big\{\omega\,\big|\, [t,t+\tau]\subseteq [0,T] \wedge N(\omega,t+\tau)-N(\omega,t)=n\big\}\big)$?

Comment: In the complement event, $N(t)$ never counts exactly $n$ events in any interval $[t,t+\tau]$. There are two cases: either $N(t)$ always counts $>n$ events on every interval $[t,t+\tau]$, or $N(t)$ always counts $<n$ on every such intervals. Crossing between these cases requires 2 Poisson events in one instant, which has probability $0$.

Comment: @M.Nestor: That is an excellent insight. Do you have any idea how to compute either case?